# Getting parametrization of a surface starting with a defining function

Tags: differential-geometry

If $\rho:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ is a defining function for a 2-dimensional surface $M$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$,i.e., $M=\{\rho=0\}$, how can one construct a local parametrization of $M$ using this defining function?

For simplicity, assume $M$ is a regular surface, $\rho$ is smooth, $|\nabla\rho|\neq0$ along $\rho=0$, etc.

I understand that one needs some kind of implicit mapping theorem but am not able to make my arguments precise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be difficult to getting an explicit formula in the general case, but here's how it goes: assume that $\rho\colon \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$ is smooth, has $0$ as a regular value, and $\rho^{-1}[\{0\}]=M$. Let $p \in M$. Since $\nabla\rho(x) \neq 0$, one of the partial derivatives of $\rho$ does not vanish at $p$. Assume that $$\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial x^n}(p) \neq 0.$$This will give us that $M$ is locally a graph with domain in the $(x^1,\ldots, x^{n-1})$-hyperplane. The argument for the other cases is the same. Define $\varphi\colon \Bbb R^{n} \to \Bbb R$ by $$\varphi(x^1,\ldots, x^{n}) = (x^1,\ldots, x^{n-1}, \rho(x^1,\ldots, x^n)).$$We have $$D\varphi(x^1,\ldots, x^n) = \begin{pmatrix} {\rm Id}_{n-1} \\ \hline \nabla\rho(x_1,\ldots,x^n),  \end{pmatrix}$$so that $$\det D\varphi(p) = \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial x^n}(p) \neq 0,$$and the Inverse Function Theorem applies: we get $U \ni p$ open such that $\varphi\colon U \to \varphi[U]$ is a diffeomorphism. The inverse necessarily has the form $$\varphi^{-1}(x^1,\ldots, x^n) = (x^1,\ldots, x^{n-1}, g(x^1,\ldots,x^n))$$for some smooth function $g$. Now, if $\pi\colon \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^{n-1}$ forgets the last entry of a vector, you may define ${\bf X}\colon \pi[U \cap M]\to U \cap M$ by $${\bf X}(x^1,\ldots, x^{n-1}) = (x^1,\ldots, x^{n-1}, g(x^1,\ldots, x^{n-1},0)),$$which is a parametrization for $M$ (this indeed takes values in $M$ since $\rho(x^1,\ldots, x^{n-1},g(x^1,\ldots, x^{n-1},0))=0$).

---

**Edit:** $D\varphi(p)$ is upper triangular with $1$'s in the diagonal except for the last entry, which is $(\partial \rho/\partial x^n)(p)$. When you wrote $\nabla \rho$ instead of $D\rho$ I assumed that you were using the word "surface" loosely here meaning codimension $1$. If the codimension of $M$ is $n-2$, you have $\rho \colon \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^{n-2}$ instead, and you can assume WLOG that the last order $n-2$ submatrix of $D\rho(p)$ is non-singular. Define $$\varphi(x^1,\ldots, x^n) = (x^1,x^2, \rho^1(x_1,\ldots, x^n),\ldots, \rho^{n-2}(x_1,\ldots, x^n))$$instead -- $\det D\varphi(p)$ will be equal to the $(n-2)\times (n-2)$ non-zero subdeterminant of $D\rho(p)$ we chose, and the IVT applies. From here on the proof goes just like in the original answer.

Comment: I think the determinant of $D\varphi(p)$ should be the reciprocal of that partial derivative. Also, I was looking for a parametrization for a surface (dimension 2 smooth manifold). For that we should get parametrization from an open set in $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @iota I added a brief edit to the answer.

Comment: I think a defining function is a function from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: If a map $\Bbb R^n\to \Bbb R^m$ with $n\geq m$ has full rank, the submanifold it defines has dimension $n-m$. This is why I raised the dimension of the codomain of $\rho$.

Comment: I understand now, I don't know what I was thinking. Thanks for the help.